# How to Curl the current version of the node

Tags: node, tezos-client

How can I curl the current version of my node? I have found how to do it on other crypto nodes but not tezos.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl https://florencenet.smartpy.io/version
```

**Output:**

> {"version":{**"major":9,"minor":1,"additional_info":"release"**},"network_version":{"chain_name":"TEZOS_FLORENCENOBANET_2021-03-04T20:00:00Z","distributed_db_version":1,"p2p_version":1},"commit_info":{"commit_hash":"31e6641db444bdb5d3fb9f232282b429b8c3ea7a","commit_date":"2021-04-30 16:58:29 +0200"}}

RPC documentation ([GET /version](https://tezos.gitlab.io/shell/rpc.html#get-version))

Comment: More correctly, `curl http://ip.of.your.node:port/version`  Most likely this is `http://127.0.0.1:8732/version`

Answer (score 1):

If you also have `jq` installed, you can have a nice clean output of the version with the following command.

```
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8732/version | jq -r '[.version.major, .version.minor] | join(".")'
```

Output

```
9.2
```